# convert mysql data to json with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I read the other questions of the same type but none brings a solution to my problem.
I have PHP code that converts the mysql data into a json file. my code works well locally but not on my online server.

Need help please what's wrong with my code?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','android');

if ($con->connect_errno) {
printf("Failed to connect to database");
exit();
}


$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY id DESC");

$dbdata = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
$dbdata[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);

?>
```

it's exactly the same code that I copied to my online server by changing login credentials but it does not work.

Comment: Check that the PHP versions match

Comment: _"but it does not work"_ means what _exactly_? any errors? The json looks wrong? ...?

Comment: I do not think that it is a problem of version since my other php script work in local and online

Comment: did you check for mysqli_error ? Did you try to run the query in a db-manager (like phpmyadmin)?

Comment: Maybe you need to check server's database details, then check step by step the $con or $result and then $row. if all these contains some real value then PHP version issue could be

Comment: @jeff I do not have any error message. lordsque i try the code in the browser i have nothing just a blank page

Comment: I suppose `error_reporting` is off on the server.. switch it on with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as first line

Comment: Not forgetting http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php which will show you if json_encode failed.

Comment: also check for [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) - do a `echo mysqli_error($con);` after your query.

Comment: I tried `error_reporting` but I still have no such error

Comment: @jeff always no error message

Comment: next steps: `var_dump($result);` then `var_dump($row);` .... debug it!

Comment: that's what I get `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(20) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: `var_dump($row)` `NULL`

Comment: Where did you put `var_dump($row)`? It should be inside the loop.

Comment: Since `$result` says `num_rows = 20`, `$dbdata` should be an array with 20 rows.

Comment: @barmar yes my table has 20 entries

Comment: There's no problem in the code you posted, it should work fine.

Comment: I do not understand why he does not send me anything in my browser